# How do I force a ListView to display a single item

Tags: android, user-interface, android-listview, custom-controls

I am trying to make a control like this image. It would reside on the left hand side of my activity and fill_parent on the height.

I want the top and bottom sections to go to the next/previous item. I was thinking a ListView with a divider might be able to do this but the main issue I am having is having the ListView only display 1 item at a time. If I have to put the ListView between 2 separate views that have their own gradient and handle moving the ListView I can.

But how do I restrain the ListView to 1 at a time? Seems simple enough but I can't figure it out. I also might have locked in to using a ListView and am overlooking a simpler alternative.

[image: listviewimage]

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at the Android Gallery class:  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html

I've used it for displaying various videos in a similar maner as you're describing here.  Although my lay out was horizontal and the user scrolled by dragging between images.

Nonetheless, I think this would be a better approach then trying to make a ListView work for you.  I certainly haven't played around with every option provided by the Gallery class.

**EDIT:**
Since the gallery class has been deprecated, the alternative seems to be the ViewFlipper:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html

Comment: This class was deprecated in API level 16. Perhaps a ViewPager is a possibility.

Comment: Not a good solution, seing as the Gallery Widget is deprecated since API 16 - use a http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html or a http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html. Don't encourage people to use deprecated code, even though it might be easier.

Comment: Sorry Fellas - the project I had used the Gallery on was a few years ago.  Didn't realize it had been deprecated. ;-)   @Darwind - certainly wouldn't "encourage" people to use deprecated code.  Update my answer accordingly.